# CSS Position Fixed with top 0 is working only on refresh

Tags: css, angular5

I have an angular 5 application where there is a route for processdetails of a process. On navigating to the route through a router link and clicking the modal pop up button  a modal pop up opens.

The Modal pop up is having css property position value fixed but it is not fixed to the top despite of giving the css property top value to 0 .

But, when i REFRESH the page the modal pop up is fixed to the top. Could someone explain why this is happening. Below is the css for the modal pop up

```
modal-popup .overlay {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: 0px;
        opacity: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        z-index: 1000;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

the modal pop up is deep inside the document elements despite of that it should work as per my knowledge as position fixed is supposed to be fixed relative to the view port

Comment: Please dont show screenshots of your problem but use the code snippet.

Comment: have you tried clearing cache and testing in private window?

Comment: Does the modal's parent element have a position property?

Comment: one of the top level parent element has a position absolute and another two parent elements have  position relative. the parent elements which are positioned are wrapper elements and element itself of a custom scroll bar implementation(eg: <xyz-scroll-bar></xyz-scroll-bar>)

Comment: tried in private window it is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ve found the issue . One of the ancestors of the modal pop up component was having transform property applied to it by an animation service created for the angular app.

> When an ancestor has the transform, perspective, or filter property
>   set to something other than none, that ancestor is used as the
>   container instead of the viewport.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

that is why the css fixed position and top value 0 is not working as expected, in this case the modal pop was not at the top. On refresh it was working fine because the animation which is setting the transform property on one of the ancestors is not triggered on refresh but only on route change